# should I choose reactjs+f7 or f7+vue.js?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, vue.js, html-framework-7

Lately I plan to rewrite my ionic app because of its poor performance on Android. I am impressed with framework7(f7)'s smoothness on Android. But it lacks data bindings, and not as elegant as react. However I do not wanna sacrifice performance too much. So I am choosing between reactjs+f7 and f7+vue.js. Reactjs+f7 can make code much more elegant, I can use flux+react-router. f7+vuejs is likely to have better performance, smaller bundle.js, I can stick to f7 built-in router and only use vue.js where I wanna use, there is more control on my side.

Comment: If you cannot make thoughtful decision yourself - flip the coin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't comment on any of the frameworks since I've been mostly doing desktop dev with Angular, but I can comment to some of the 2 primary concerns that you alluded to:

- performance
- development ease.

On all of the projects I've worked on, any time a choice of performance over development ease came about, development ease was the simple choice.

Here's why: Technology will always improve, eventually mitigating most performance concerns. Unless the framework just completely tanks your CPU, which you'd notice and have heard about, it will eventually smooth out.  Plus you can always performance-tweak things later....

Things that improve your day to day experience and keep you happy at your work are harder to come by.  I say choose what will allow you to be your most productive. Based on what you've suggested, the ReactJS + F7 would be my 1st

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Have you ventured down this path yet? Have you found that it scales pretty well? We're trying to evaluate this option, ReactJs + F7.

Comment: I have not.  I recently started a new personal project and have been looking at Angular 2.  I made that decision mainly to learn about NG2 and Typescript.  I have really made little progress on this though and recently have been questioning if I want to invest more of my time in another Google product.  They dictate usage paradigms pretty heavily and I want to explore what others have to offer.  But again this is a personal project so development pains are more for self-improvement.  If this were a work project, I'd choose as I suggested to you, by what makes my day-to-day work pleasant.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Please consider my project here https://pors.github.io/reactionic as an alternative. It's a port of Ionic for React.

Comment: 3+ years later, I have finally delved into Vue.js (ver 2).  Rather than getting bogged down in learning the latest and greatest, I just said "just choose something".  Sometimes you just have to dive in and learn to swim.